# alpha regex does not pick out alpha chars in bash

Tags: regex, macos, unix

I am on OSX 10.9.4 trying to convert this python regex `p = "(2024 (?:(?:(?:[a-z|.]+ ?)+)) 93)"` to Unix regex to improve speed of grep.

To test (and start), I am running `grep --color -e "[:alpha:]" /Volumes/USB/Corpus/MaskedContracts_Pre_N/01-01-09-Maximus-Inc-Second-Amendment.txt` to try and find [alpha](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format) characters in the file. I would think this would select all of the alpha characters but it only picks out some of them. Am I missing something in the docs (linked)? What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not on OSX, but my version of `grep` (version 2.12 on Linux) actually returns a message that is pretty descriptive when you try to use `-e '[:alpha:]'`:

> grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]

In other words, the syntax is to use `[:alpha:]` **inside** a bracket expression, which means the final syntax will have nested brackets: `[[:alpha:]]`.

This is logical, when you think about it, as there would be no way for a regex engine to disambiguate `[:alpha:]` between the character class, and just the characters `:, a, l, p, and h`

Answer (score 2):

In your regex:

```
[:alpha:]
```

is a character class looking for one of a, l, p, h, :, so there are the highlighted characters you are seeing. What you really want is:

```
grep -e '[[:alpha:]]'
```

Also, if you only want the characters you match in the output try the `-o` flag:

```
grep -oe '[[:alpha:]]'
```